# SharePoint list new item through SoapEnvelope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint, soap

I am trying to make a new item inside a SharePoint list using JavaScript, jQuery and Ajax, this is my function:

```
function CreateItem(Title) { 
var soapEnv =          
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +         
"xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" " +          
"xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +      
"<soapenv:Body>" +                           
"<UpdateListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">" +     
"<listName>listName</listName>" +                
"<updates>" +                          
"<Batch OnError=\"Continue\">" +           
"<Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"New\">" +            
"<Field Name=\"ID\">New</Field>" +            
"<Field Name=\"Title\">" + Title + "</Field>" +    
"</Method>" +                    
"</Batch>" +                         
"</updates>" +                        
"</UpdateListItems>" +               
"</soapenv:Body>" +                  
"</soapenv:Envelope>";               
$.ajax({     
url: "http://URL/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
type: "POST",                           
dataType: "xml",                        
data: soapEnv,                         
beforeSend: function (xhr) {             
xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",           
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems"); 
},                           
complete: processCreateResultSuccess,    
contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",    
error: processCreateResultError             
});
```

}

This part works fine, I am able to create a new item with the Title that gets passed in the function. But I also want to add a description to this item when I create it, and adding:

```
"<Field Name=\"Description\">" + "a description" + "</Field>" +
```

doesn't work, why is this, and how should I do it?

Comment: I am using this method because It's from a Apache Cordova app, and this was the only way I got it to work (atleast with the title), how can I see if it's the internal name? I have made this field myself, and named it 'Description'

Comment: nevermind! It worked, thanks! I did a fast google on how to retrive the internal name, and it turns out it was 'DeviationDescription', since it's a part of the Deviation list, if u make your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked whether this field exists and that you're using its internal name? And another thing, I was curious why you are using this method? Can't you use the client object model to do these actions?